# Custom Line Chart

Tags: javascript, spotfire

How to make changes in highcharts time series zoomable chart to get similar to the one mentioned in below link:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

Used JS : 
$.getJSON(
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/usdeur.json',
    function (data) {

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data
        }]
    });
}
```

);

Comment: sorry what is your question? that if you use the same code of this example you won't see the xAxis zooming the date time?

Comment: Hi quirimmo, I guess i missed to mention, I would like to have above chart (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) in spotfire, what changes i need to do.?